# How to create view in Azure Synapse Serverless pool for a Lake Database

Tags: sql, azure-synapse

I have a Lake Database created in Synapse Studio as a Workspace and I am trying to create a VIEW for the table. I right click on table and select "New SQL Script" and I get a pre generated script as ""

```
SELECT TOP (100) [AssetId],[AssetName],[AssetDescription],[AssetModelId]
FROM [Utilities_66_Demo].[dbo].[Asset]
```

Now I would like to create a view just for testing. How can I do that. I tried the simple syntax as we use to do in Sql but it fails. Can someone please show how can I create a View here. Again its a Lake Database in Workspace tab in Synapse studio

Comment: Please post the syntax that you used and the error that occured. Don't make us guess

Answer (score 1):

To generate the new script for creating a view, you can right-click on the viewsNew SQL script New view and change the table name or script.

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: The FROM needs to be the fully qualified value for Lake Database: [Utilities_66_Demo].[dbo].[Asset] in this case.